# How can I delete an existing skype contact?

Tags: applescript, skype

How can I remove a contact on Skype using applescript? If possible is there a way to do this without Skype asking you for permission to be controlled?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't think its possible. Skype has removed the ability to be scriptable.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23030718#23030718